# When exporting from PowerPoint to PDF, how do I prevent image compression?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

It seems Powerpoint is compressing the images in my slides (each slide in my powerpoint is 1 large image). I have turned off image compression in the advanced settings.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing which version of PowerPoint you have and what method you're using to make the PDF.

Comment: Where is the option to turn off image compression? I don't see it in PowerPoint 2007.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Powerpoint 2007 or 2010 then the max DPI it will save a PDF at is 220, even if image compression is turned off.

You could install PDF printer software like PDFCreator then "print" your presentation, make sure to check the High Quality checkbox. In PDFCreator click Options then Formats -> Compression and change the compression from Automatic to the level of compression you want e.g. JPEG-Minimum. I wouldn't recommend completely turning off compression as this will create a huge PDF document.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

Comment: Great! It really works!

Comment: But actually I goy into another problem: pages are rotaded... Can't find how to fix that :(

Comment: Solved it: set `Paper Feed Directon` to `Short Edge First (flipped)`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the export bitmap resolution may be increased to a maximum of **300DPI** by making the following registry change for the corresponding version of PowerPoint:

```
2016 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options
2013 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Options
2010 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\PowerPoint\Options
2007 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\PowerPoint\Options
2003 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

Add a new **DWORD** value, **ExportBitmapResolution** and set it to decimal **300**.

Full info from Microsoft at : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827745/en-gb

Comment: Doesn't work for me with PowerPoint 2016.

Comment: It seems that this only works for bitmap as the setting suggested. PDFs are not bitmaps but vector graphics.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.zamzar.com/convert/ppt-to-pdf/ - I have spent about half a day testing different online and offline methods. At the end the one that I found to convert a presentation to PDF with a perfect quality is **Zamzar**.

**Things that I have tried and the image quality is still terrible**

1. Creating a Google Presentation and export as PDF: **Fail**
2. Converting a Power Point presentation to PDF: **Fail**
3. Trying the registry trick as suggested by Microsoft: **Fail** (I don't
   why, no difference still).

Comment: Registry hack doesn't apply to PDF because PDF is not a bitmap. Zamzar does a pretty good job.

Comment: Zamzar does not have all Fonts available. Pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, 2 easy steps

1. Save the Powerpoint as PNG first, it would be in several files if you have more than one slide
2. Just search for "convert png to pdf" in Google and use an online tool to convert PNG to PDF

That should work

Comment: In case one wants a higher DPI, set the key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options` `ExportBitmapResolution` (`REG_DWORD`) to (decimal) `600` DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Use a PDF printer.
Try printing to a [PDFCreator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) "Printer", then it will output from the RAW .prn file a PDF, which should containt your Resolution settings.

I normally don't support using 3rd party software, but sometimes you have no choice. In my cases it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me on Powerpoint 2010, with Adobe Acrobat installed:

1. Set the quality settings to maximum in the options menu
2. Select "File"
3. Select "Save As", (NOT "Save as Adobe PDF")
4. Select "PDF (*.pdf)" in the file type dropdown menu
5. Save the file

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a while.  You can delete everything else on a slide and save your background as a picture file and when you Format Background, import that File.  Now the background will show up in the .pdf file.

Comment: Can you explain how this is an answer to the question?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best resolution and very satisfied,
File> Print > Choose Microsoft print to PDF (as your printer) > Click printer properties > Advanced > Change the paper size to A3 > OK > OK > Print. DONE
You will get almost the same image quality

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It isn't clear what this adds to the existing answers.  If you are making a new point can you better differentiate it?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is

1. Print the file to A3 format [good resolution, but wrong dimensions]
2. Open the .pdf file with a pdf editor (e.g. Photoshop) and save in correct dimensions. [usually widescreen, e.g. some multiple of 1920x1080]

--

PDFCreator did the same as print to A3 (wrong dimension). Save to PNG led to resolution loss. Save to .emf led to wrong dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, using Micros**t Office Professional Plus 2019, I wasn't able to save the pdf compression-free (or at least at a reasonable size and image compression).

However, I was able to export it as a pdf by using PDF24.

1. Install [PDF24 Creator](https://www.pdf24.org/)
2. In Powerpoint, go to File > Print, select PDF24 as printer
3. Go to Printer settings right below the printer selection. In this dialog, click "Extended..." (in the bottom right).
4. Select the paper size you want. In Graphics > Printing quality, select a high quality, e.g. 1200 dpi (600 might work as well). Then click OK, OK.
5. Print. A few seconds after, a dialog from PDF24 pops up.
6. In this dialog, click "Save as PDF". **Important:** In the general settings, cooose "Best Quality" for "Quality of the pdf".
7. (Optional) If you had title, author and tags in your pptx document, you can also add them in the "Info" section (check "use information" in this case). They will be shown in the document settings of the pdf (and, for example, are useful for citation programs).