# When exporting from PowerPoint to PDF, how do I increase bitmap image resolution?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, export

Unfortunately, the well-known registry solution described for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/376675/when-exporting-from-powerpoint-to-pdf-how-do-i-prevent-image-compression) does not work when exporting to PDF.

With this registry hack, pages **exported e.g as JPEG or PNG** *will* be saved with a correspondingly high resolution -- in newer versions of PowerPoint even without the [previous limitation to 307 dpi](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/powerpoint/change-export-slide-resolution#:%7E:text=3072).

However, when **exporting to PDF**, all bitmaps contained in a PowerPoint slide are only embedded in the PDF at low resolution (200 dpi in my case).

It would be great if someone had the information where the **bitmap resolution for PDF generation** from PowerPoint is saved, so that this resolution could be increased.

Answer (score 2):

Exporting to PDF takes a completely different path than exporting images, so the DPI registry hack that works for JPG et al will have no effect on PDFs.

Assuming you're using PPT's own Save As | choose PDF export rather than an add-in from Adobe or other PDF printer driver supplier, here are a few things that will have an effect:

Check File | Options | Advanced
Scroll to Image Size & Quality
Put a check next to Do Not Compress
If the checkmark's not already there, any images you've already inserted will already be compressed; you'll need to delete and re-insert them.

If there are any empty Content or picture placeholders on a slide, delete them before you insert images; images inserted into placeholders WILL be compressed. Period. Regardless of your Do Not Compress setting. This may have been fixed in the most recent versions of PPT, so test first if you wish.

When saving your PDF, be sure to choose the Standard Publishing ...etc option

Comment: All of this I have tried already. Specifically, the images are not compressed in the PowerPoint file but of native resolution. 

Opening the PPT file e.g. in LibreOffice Impress and exporting it from there to PDF leaves them in their native resolution.

Comment: To help understand this better, how are you determining that the files in PPT are still in native resolution and how are you measuring the resolution in the PDF? I know you can do the first by unzipping the PPTX and extracting the images. I don't know offhand how to do the second. Thanks!

Comment: If I drag the images larger in PowerPoint and then zoom in, a high resolution is still visible. Likewise, when printing from PowerPoint to PDF, the images are still in high resolution. In summary, I haven't tried it exactly yet, but I strongly suspect that the images in PowerPoint remain in their original resolution with my current PowerPoint settings.

The resolution of images in a PDF can be determined e.g. in PDF-XChange Editor with the function "Recompress Image", which shows all information about a selected image:
https://i.imgur.com/S6k82Hx.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately, on my main PC, I even get only 100 dpi bitmap resolution when exporting from PowerPoint to PDF: https://i.imgur.com/V3anMzA.png instead of 200 dpi on all other PCs: https://i.imgur.com/UOmpPDU.png
All computers run Windows 10 and PowerPoint 2019/365 in the latest version. Thankful for any advice on what could be causing this extremely low resolution on PC1. Here's the PPT file: https://file.io/ZIXjRgwdbGnP

Comment: Thanks for the sample files. That helped, and I think I have the answer. When you save as a PDF from, you have the option of choosing Minimum Size or Standard Publishing (depending on how you access the Save As feature, you may have to click an Options link to see this. I exported as both, zoomed in on both and found that Minimum Size gives me a duplicate of your 100dpi version, where Standard Publishing gives me a dupe of your 200dpi example. I don't seem to be able to get Minimum Size to "stick" as the default, though; some kind of registry setting on your PC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, those settings do not help on my main PC. The "Compress Images" setting is set to "High Fidelity" and the PDF export options are set to "Standard Publishing". Yet, on that one PC, I always get the poor 100dpi resolution. True, it might actually be a registry setting, but I can't seem to find it. The problem is even present when I don't use PowerPoint for the conversion but PDF-XChange Editor (PDF-XChange Editor  uses the PowerPoint "engine" for this, without actually starting PowerPoint):
https://forum.tracker-software.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=35402

Comment: Other than suggesting that you turn image compression off rather than choosing High Fidelity (you'll have to delete then re-import the images after doing this), I'm at a loss.

Comment: Thanks. I turned image compression off now, but this didn't affect the bitmap resolution in exported PDF's, both for the "Glow" effect and for other images. I shall try and ask for advice in the Microsoft community forum now, and will report back should there be any other ideas.

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page ... you turned compression off THEN re-inserted the images, correct? Just turning compression off won't affect images you've already inserted. They're already compressed.

Comment: Yes. However only the "Glow" (and similar shadow effects) are affected by this issue. Other contained images are exported to PDF with 200 dpi.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I didn't catch that detail, David.

Comment: Yes Steve, I also was not clear enough about this distinction between the rendering of the 'Glow' effect and normal bitmap images initially.

Comment: This does not work at all correctly; for reference, I've opened and exported the same .pptx in LibreOffice Impress and the export has the full image quality. Whatever I set as told by this answer in Powerpoint doesn't work. Period.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the effective bitmap resolution by increasing the slide size in PowerPoint.

For this, go to the `Design` tab > `Slide Size` > `Custom Slide Size`. Standard slide sizes for 16:9 slides are 13.33 in x 7.5 in - up these to 40 x 22.5 to effectively triple the bitmap resolution.

Ideally, you do this before starting your presentation. If you do not, PowerPoint will scale up the existing content (bitmaps, text etc.). In my case, most custom slide properties were maintained - only default font colors and enumeration symbols were lost, and margins did not seem to be scaled up.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed seems to be the only way around this problem at the moment.

Comment: This has the additional advantage that you can zoom in more on the slide while drawing, since PowerPoint limits the maximum zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Save to PDF you can print to PDF. this preserves the resolution of the images.
File>Print>Choose PDF from the printer list>click printer properties and set the resolution (and paper size in custom if required). then press ok and print.

Comment: That's true, however this does not preserve, inter alia, object transparencies. Instead, overlapped object areas are rendered with bad (pixelated) quality, even when the objects are vector objects.